# kerberos Spnego Springboot Application

Tags: spring-boot, web-config, spring-ldap, spnego

I am trying to implement a browser based single sign on using SPNEGO with Tomcat.

I have followed all the instructions on these two pages:

```
http://spnego.sourceforge.net/pre_flight.html
http://spnego.sourceforge.net/spnego_tomcat.html
```

When I accessed hello_spnego.jsp work fine and return user

but I need to add configuration in spring boot standalone application here is class configuration

```
@WebFilter("/*") 
public class ExampleSpnegoAuthenricatorValue implements Filter {
private final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(ExampleSpnegoAuthenricatorValue.class.getName());
@Override
public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {

}

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain  filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
  HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
    LOGGER.info("start Here -------------------------------------");

    LOGGER.info(httpServletRequest.getRemoteUser());
    LOGGER.info(httpServletRequest.getSession().getId());
    Enumeration<String> headerNames = httpServletRequest.getHeaderNames();

    if (headerNames != null) {
        while (headerNames.hasMoreElements()) {
            System.out.println("Header: " + httpServletRequest.getHeader(headerNames.nextElement()));
        }
    }

    LOGGER.info(httpServletRequest.getRequestedSessionId());
    LOGGER.info("end Here -------------------------------------");
    // Get the IP address of client machine.


    // Log the IP address and current timestamp.

    // Pass request back down the filter chain
    filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest,servletResponse);
}

@Override
public void destroy() {

 }
}
```

RemoteUser is null ?? and this error showing :
HTTP Status 500 - GSSException: Failure unspecified at GSS-API level (Mechanism level: Checksum failed)

type Exception report

message GSSException: Failure unspecified at GSS-API level (Mechanism level: Checksum failed)

I have verified that the account used to talk to the KDC is working correctly. Also, I have the username and password specified in the web.xml file, so I don't have a separate KeyTab file.

For diagnosis purposes I'm add two files krb5.conf and login.conf files:

Since I don't have a keytab file, it's not mentioned in the login.conf file.

FYI, I'm using Tomcat 8 and JDK 1.8.

I would really appreciate some insight on what's happening here. If you need more information, please let me know. Thanks in advance!

Comment: here remote user is coming null which seems it is not able to get the user principle. Please refer this tutorial which have working example with spnego and spring boot. https://www.thetechnojournals.com/2019/12/integratedkerberos-authentication-using.html

Comment: thank you for reply me ,I'm look to this way in a official docs but I mention in my post I don't have a separate KeyTab file.